# ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING doesn't stop query continuing with next insert statement

Tags: postgresql

I'm using WITH to run two INSERT statements (table A & table B). The first INSERT statement has an ON CONFLICT CLAUSE, if there is a duplication in A.name, DO NOTHING. The second statement relies on a successful insertion into table A, and so it tries to enter null values into table B. DO NOTHING does nothing for the first statement but the second one continues, how do I stop it?

```sql
WITH first_insert AS (INSERT INTO 
                groups(group_cuid,group_name,created_by,date_created)
                VALUES ($1,$2,(SELECT user_id 
                               FROM users 
                               WHERE users.cognito_id='${created_by}'), 
                (SELECT now()::timestamp))
                ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT group_name_unique DO NOTHING
                RETURNING id,created_by
                )
INSERT INTO groups_users_rel(group_id,user_id,is_admin,date_joined)
VALUES (
        (SELECT id FROM first_insert),
        (SELECT created_by FROM first_insert),
        true, 
        (SELECT now()::timestamp)
       )
RETURNING *
```

If an insert happens in GROUPS table, I want an insert into GROUPS_USERS_REL table. If there is a conflict, I want the whole query to end. Instead, there are null values inserted into GROUPS_USERS_REL based off the CONFLICT in the first insert.

If there's easier ways to do any of this feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` will always try to insert exactly one record using the list of values you supplied. When the query `SELECT id FROM first_insert` returns no records, then the subquery `(SELECT id FROM first_insert)` will evaluate to `NULL`, so that's what ends up in your table.

If you want to insert a variable number of rows (i.e. zero or one), then you need an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement, with the `SELECT` deciding which rows to add (if any).

In your case, it would look like this:

```
WITH first_insert AS (
  ...
)
INSERT INTO groups_users_rel(group_id,user_id,is_admin,date_joined)
SELECT
  id,
  created_by,
  true, 
  now()::timestamp
FROM first_insert
RETURNING *
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by [Nick Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104979/nick-barnes) solves the problem you experience. However, I noticed another opportunity to *clean up* your code:

Instead of using a `VALUES` clause, `SELECT user_id FROM users`, and provide the constants to insert through the query parameters. Making the full query text:

```
WITH first_insert AS (
INSERT INTO groups (group_cuid, group_name, created_by, date_created)
  SELECT 
      $1
    , $2
    , user_id
    , now()
  FROM users
  WHERE users.cognito_id = '${created_by}'
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT group_name_unique DO NOTHING
  RETURNING id, created_by, true, now()
)
INSERT INTO groups_users_rel (group_id, user_id, is_admin, date_joined)
SELECT *
FROM first_insert 
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.